# Camunda cannot execute groovy script

Tags: groovy, camunda

Here is my dependencies.

```
compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp', version: '3.0.0'

compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.5.2', ext: 'pom'
```

Here is the error message, it seems like cannot find engine.

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy': scriptEngine is null
```

Here is my script task xml format.

```
<bpmn:scriptTask id="Task_17h6w6s" name="changeStatus" scriptFormat="groovy">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1mvf31j</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_19je5yh</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:script>execution.setVariable("status", APPROVED);
</bpmn:script>
    </bpmn:scriptTask>
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I already resolved it.

Just add this dependency.

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.15'
```

Answer (score 1):

Published https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmrun-add-to-dockerimg to achieve this (and other customisations) based on the Camunda BPM Run Docker image.