# Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy': scriptEngine is null

Tags: maven, spring-boot, groovy, workflow, camunda

[image]

Error:

1. Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy': scriptEngine is null] with root cause
2. org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy': scriptEngine is null

My code XML :

[image]

Comment: Please do not post XML as an image - XML is a text..

Comment: @ChaymaKhlifi _Commenting_ is not _posting_ (a question or answer). You can edit your question with the "edit" link to the left below your question's tags. And, POM content is XML, as well.

Comment: @ChaymaKhlifi Have you seen [Camunda cannot execute groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52547810/1744774) already?

Comment: @GeroldBroser yes i have seen but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency this issue will be resolved

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-jsr223</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Camunda 7 supports scripting with JSR-223 compatible script engine implementations.
Depending on th Camund aversion you are using, the script engine may be included or not. See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/process-engine/scripting/

> We include GraalVM JavaScript in the pre-packaged Camunda
> distributions. Consult JavaScript Considerations for further
> information.
>
> We include Groovy in the pre-packaged Camunda distributions.

It looks like you are using a distribution, which is older / does not bundle groovy. You need to include the script engine of choice.

Groovy can be included by adding the **groovy-jsr223 runtime** to your POM, e.g. as done here: https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda7-groovy/blob/a5b224336d93721a633620e4011efc5c69ea0e01/pom.xml#L76

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-jsr223</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.15</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the complete working example project:
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda7-groovy

You can find the latest groovy runtime verison number here: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=groovy.git